# I can't install Windows and Linux through usb

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, installation

I am trying to install Windows or Linux on my machine. After the initial boot up I can select an option to install but on the next step, when I need to select a partition, installer doesn't show me anything.

This not detect media and don't work mouse and keyboard for installing Linux, Linux live or Windows.

Generally USB don't work after select options for install Windows or run live Windows and Linux.

Comment: You need to provide additional details of your setup like processor, motherboard, BIOS and its version, Linux version, Windows version etc. Also type of instillation media and mouse and keyboard type(USB/ PS2).

Comment: my laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad500 15lsk <br/> BIOS = CFCN24WW (v1.06) <br/> CPU = i7 6500U 2.50GHz <br/> Windows 10 is currently installed and i want install Kali Linux .thank you for your help

Comment: Does your current install of Windows 10 boot reliably, or do you get errors regarding the drive/no OS found?

Comment: Your question title says, “install Windows ***and*** Linux,” your question body says, “install Windows ***or*** Linux” (and later mentions “install Windows or run live Windows and Linux”), and you have written a comment that says, “Windows 10 is currently installed and i [sic] want [sic] install Kali Linux.”  So I have no idea what you actually want. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question if you care to make it clearer and more complete. I say “if” because you rolled back an edit by one of our major users that was trying to clean up/clarify your question — why did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Download G parted Live and burn it to a CD. Run it and then delete all partitions. Then format and partition the entire drive. After you do this hit APPLY CHANGES! Now try reinstalling your O.S.